# same limit for sequence and subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Consider a sequence $(x_n \in \mathbb{Z} )_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

Consider a function $f(x_n)$ such that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} f(x_n) = K$. Then, given any subsequence $b_m = x_{n_m}$,

do we still have $\lim_{m \to +\infty} f(x_{n_m}) = K$?

If yes, do I have to show anything or is it just true?

Comment: Use the definition of *limitation* to show it is right.

Comment: Note since a limit gives that for *all* $n$ greater than some $n_0$ the function value is within a certain small distance of $K$, then this will also be true for any subset of $n$ greater than $n_0$.

Comment: It is a good exercise to prove that in any topological space, a sequence converges if and only if all of its subsequences converge. (Note that in arbitrary topological spaces, sequences can have more than one limit.)